What is the proper way to configure the CLUT in an STM32H7?
I have an STM32H7A3 that is connected to a parallel (24-bit) RGB display.  I would like to use the CLUT to save space in memory.  I have the LTDC peripheral configured in L8 mode with a single layer using the graphic interface in STM32CubeIDE, and the code generation seems to produce everything correctly, except that it doesn't do any of the CLUT initialization.  I found a few HAL functions, notably HAL_LTDC_ConfigCLUT and HAL_LTDC_EnableCLUT that seem like they can be used to configure and enable the CLUT, but when I attempt to call either of these functions (before enabling the LTDC peripheral), it causes the call to HAL_LTDC_ConfigLayer not to enable the layer (the layer 1 CR register is 0x0).  I have a feeling this is somehow related to the shadow register functionality of the LTDC peripheral, but even when I explicitly update the registers with LTDC->SRCR |= LTDC_SRCR_IMR it fails to enable the layer.  What am I missing here?

Are you using TouchGFX (or similar)?

No, I'm just trying to get a basic setup going.  My screen buffer is just a hard-coded test pattern.
